# Select documents of a collection depending on user roles

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to get all documents of a collection which has a specific value for a field (`section`) - which depends on a user role - or an userId for the field `user`.

So I'm trying to check if the user is in a role and put that into the query:

```
var sectionOne = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['something']) ? { section: 'cars' } : undefined;
var sectionSecond = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['anything']) ? { section: 'vegetables' } : undefined;
var sectionThird = Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['else']) ? { section: 'countries' } : undefined;

var count = Collection.find(
    {
        $or: [
            sectionOne,
            sectionSecond,
            sectionThird,
            { user: userId },
        ],
        read: { 
            $nin: [ userId ] 
        }
    }
).count();

console.log(count);
```

What would be the correct way to do that?

For better understanding here an example of what I'm trying to do:

**Example**

If the user has the roles `something` and `else`, then the query should look like this:

```
var count = Collection.find(
    {
        $or: [
            { section: 'cars' },
            { section: 'countries' },
            { user: userId },
        ],
        read: { 
            $nin: [ userId ] 
        }
    }
).count();
```

So all documents which has `cars` or `countries` or a userId and the userId is not in the read-array will be selected with that, right?

**Update**

I think my question is not precise enough. So let me explain it a bit better:

I want to get all docs of collection with `user: userId` - if there are any docs which matches this.

Additional (!) I need to get all docs which matches `section: 'cars'` if the user has the role `something`. So in this case there will be more results.

If the user has also the role `anything` I also want to get the results of `section: 'vegetables'` and add them to the result. So all of these things are not depending on each other.

Excluding the last thing `read: { $nin: [ userId ] }`: This should be a needed thing for every single match described above.

Comment: That's the way I would read that query. What's your actual question?

Comment: There is an extra comma at the end of `$or` array. This may cause an error.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Updated the question to make it more clear. Hope you understand me...